# Can't change screen with TabIcon in react native?

Tags: react-native

I have an issue when changing screens. If i pressed in the middle of the `tabIcon` it's not navigating to the screen but if i clicked a little bit left further the screen changes. I think that like there is a sort of a `View` in `absolute` above that is preventing me from pressing ([Element inspector](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BZZ8h.png)).

I have my code like this :

```js
<Tab.Navigator
        initialRouteName="HomeNavigator"
        tabBarOptions={{
          showLabel: false,
          keyboardHidesTabBar: true,
          labelStyle: {
            color: 'red'
          },
          style: {
            backgroundColor: '#008D36' ,
            paddingTop: 10,
            paddingBottom: 10,
            minHeight: 65,
            color: '#ffffff',
            borderTopColor: '#ffffff',
            justifyContent: 'flex-start',
            alignItems: 'flex-start'
,          }
        }}
      >
        <Tab.Screen
          name="Home"
          component={HomeNavigator}
          options={(navigation, route) => ({
            title: 'Home',
            tabBarIcon: ({ props, focused }) => (
              <TouchableWithoutFeedback {...props} >
              <View style={{flex: 2, alignItems: 'center'}}>
                <Image source={LOGO1} resizeMode="contain" style={[styles.imgSize, focused && { opacity:1 }]} />
                <Text style={[styles.label, focused && { opacity:1, textDecorationLine: 'underline' }]}>Home</Text>
              </View>
            </TouchableWithoutFeedback>
            )
          })}
        />
        <Tab.Screen
          name="Home2"
          component={HomeNavigator}
          options={(navigation, route) => ({
            title: 'Home2',
            tabBarIcon: ({ props, focused }) => (
              <TouchableWithoutFeedback {...props} >
              <View style={{flex: 2, alignItems: 'center'}}>
                <Image source={LOGO2} resizeMode="contain" style={[styles.imgSize, focused && { opacity:1 }]} />
                <Text style={[styles.label, focused && { opacity:1, textDecorationLine: 'underline' }]}>Home2</Text>
              </View>
            </TouchableWithoutFeedback>
            )
          })}
        />
</Tab.Navigator>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that `flex: 2` is out of place at this position of the tabBarIcon. You can use alignItems or justifyContent without telling the view for flex.

```
<TouchableWithoutFeedback {...props} >
          <View style={{alignItems: 'center'}}>
            <Image source={LOGO1} resizeMode="contain" style={[styles.imgSize, focused && { opacity:1 }]} />
            <Text style={[styles.label, focused && { opacity:1, textDecorationLine: 'underline' }]}>Home</Text>
          </View>
</TouchableWithoutFeedback>
```